# Using command window in Octave debug mode

Tags: matlab, octave

When my running script reaches a break point, it pauses as expected. When I try to execute a command using the command window like plotting a vector, modifying a value or even displaying it, the script resumes execution -- a behavior not found in Matlab.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: This works for me without any problems. You should describe your setup better and add a mvce

Comment: Are you using the GUI or CLI? Which version of GNU Octave? On BSD, GNU/Linux or MacOS? Which distribution?